# shmat() Permission denied even i have read access

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory

In my simple code:

```
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    key_t key = ftok(".", 'b');
    int shmid = shmget(key, 4, IPC_CREAT | 0444);
    if (shmid == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        return 1;
    }

    void* addr = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if (addr == (void*) -1) {
        perror("shmat");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("success");
    return 0;
}
```

I already have read access, but I got "shmat: Permission denied".

Do I have permission to write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man shmat`:

> If  `SHM_RDONLY`  is  specified in shmflg, the segment is attached for reading and the process must have read permission for the segment.  Otherwise the segment is attached for read and write and the process must have read and write permission for the segment.

So you need to use `SHM_RDONLY` instead of `0` when calling `shmat()`.

Comment: @Wonter: You can detach and attach again.

Comment: what about mprotect() ??